# Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error express firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I have a simple route post route in express, which I created an authentication middleware for.

```
app.post("/add-recipe", FireBaseAuth, (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.body.trim() === "") {
    return res.status(400).json({ body: "Recipe cannot be empty" });
  }

  const newRecipe = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.user.handle,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  };
  db.collection("recipes")
    .add(newRecipe)
    .then((doc) => {
      res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created sucessfully` });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

When I added my authentication middleware (below) I get the following error

```
Require stack:
- /Users/persona/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Here is the middleware

```
const FireBaseAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  let idToken;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")
  ) {
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
  } else {
    console.error("No token found");
    return res.status(403).json({ error: "Unauthorized" });
  }
  admin //verify token was issued by the food app and not someone else
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
      req.user = decodedToken;
      console.log(decodedToken);
      return db
        .collection("users")
        .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid)
        .limit(1)
        .get();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().handle;
      return next(); //allows request to proceed.
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error while verifying token", err);
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ Error: "You are not authorized to make this request" });
    });
};
```

I cannot understand as t0 why this is throwing this error.

Comment: Hi @user6248190 could you provide a more complete error log? Right now all we can see is that "something raised an error" which is going to make it tough to find the problem.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn that is the complete error I am seeing in the terminal